# Outlook not rendering my CSS in Signature

Tags: html, css, outlook

I have put a css in my outlook signature, however when I send an email it doesn't work.

```html
<head>
<style> 
.typewriter h4 {
  overflow: hidden; /* Ensures the content is not revealed until the animation */
  border-right: .15em solid orange; /* The typwriter cursor */
  white-space: nowrap; /* Keeps the content on a single line */
  margin: 0 auto; /* Gives that scrolling effect as the typing happens */
  letter-spacing: .15em; /* Adjust as needed */
  animation: 
    typing 3.5s steps(40, end),
    blink-caret .75s step-end infinite;
}

/* The typing effect */
@keyframes typing {
  from { width: 0 }
  to { width: 30% }
}

/* The typewriter cursor effect */
@keyframes blink-caret {
  from, to { border-color: transparent }
  50% { border-color: orange; }
}
</style>
</head>



<div class="typewriter">
  <h4>Gaurang Shah</h4>
</div>
```

Above is my code, however in email signature I see no movement in Text.

Comment: Most of the email clients don't support animation property. list of supported clients and properties https://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/animations/animation/. You can add a gif

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, Outlook doesn’t support animation property. You could refer to this link:

https://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/animations/animation/

However, if possible, you could try use GIF to achieve your request.

For more information, please see the following link:

[The animated graphic in my e-mail message doesn't work](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/the-animated-graphic-in-my-e-mail-message-doesn-t-work-a5e8a2a3-9d86-4203-8920-c88cb8739e34)

Comment: Animated gif are also not supported by outlook, it only shows the first frame.

Comment: There is no way to view the animated graphic directly in Outlook. You could view the message in your Web browser to see the animation. You could reference this link:https://support.office.com/en-us/article/the-animated-graphic-in-my-e-mail-message-doesn-t-work-a5e8a2a3-9d86-4203-8920-c88cb8739e34